# How to force a type on FileReader result?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that converts a PDF to a string:

```
addFile = async (file: File): Promise<Observable<File>> =>  {
  console.log(await this.getBase64(file))
  const body = {
    document: (await this.getBase64(file)).split(',')[1]
  }
  return this.http.post<File>(parseDocumentUrl, body, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}

getBase64(file: File) {
  return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = ()  => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });
}
```

The issue is that the `resolve(reader.result)` type is not compatible with the the `string` return type on the promise on the `getBase64` function:

> Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | PromiseLike'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | PromiseLike'.

I need to use `split` to remove the first part (`data:application/pdf;base64,`) of the returned string.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy fix:

```
  getBase64(file: File) {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
       const reader = new FileReader();
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       reader.onload = ()  => resolve(<string>reader.result);
       reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
 }
```

I've casted the result of `read.result` to a `string`.